# Rotate Half of Object While Keeping Other Half in Same Position?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

When I try to rotate half of my object, the other half moves along with it.

[image]

How do I make it only rotate while keeping the non selected side in the same position?

[image]

Basically I want to form an L shape but regular rotation isn't working and i tried switching the origin points as well, but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the 3D cursor at the center of your mesh and choose *3D Cursor* as *Pivot Point*:

[image]

Rotate on the right axis:

[image]

As it will deform your mesh, correct it with the *Snap to Vertex* option in order to align with the vertices:

[image]